# What does the code this@MainActivity mean?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner of Kotlin, the following code is from a webpage, I can't understand that the parameter `this@MainActivity` in the code `layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)`,  Could you tell me? Thanks!

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import mobi.porquenao.poc.kotlin.R

class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
    lateinit var listAdapter: MainAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        with (list) {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            listAdapter = MainAdapter()
            adapter = listAdapter
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        listAdapter.add()
        list.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: May be its Context

Comment: it says the current class

Comment: it refers the current clas context

Answer (score 7):

It is a **qualified** `this`, used to access `MainActivity`'s context from an outer scope.

```
class MainActivity {
    fun onCreate() {
        val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
        with (list) {
            println(this)              // >>> [1, 2, 3]
            println(this@MainActivity) // >>> MainActivity@2a84aee7
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about this approach in Kotlin *[documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified)*.

Answer (score 3):

```
this@MainActivity
```

refers the current class context, similar to the MainActivity.this in Java

Answer (score 1):

`this@MainActivity` is the context to better understand:

```
Kotlin:                Java:

this@MainActivity == MainActivity.this
```

Answer (score 1):

It is used to reference an outer scope. this means that `this` is from the scope `MainActivity`.
You can find more info about that here. [this expressions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html)

Also, it is used in extension functions.

Say you extend the String object.

```
fun String.Capitalize(){
//some logic here
this.@Capitalize // this references the receiver of Capitalize i.e any string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with(list)
```

changes everything in that block as if we are in the class of which 'list' is an instance. You can see that in the first line:

```
setHasFixedSize(true)
```

This is a method that has to be called on a recyclerview, this is not a method which exists in MainActivity. Now, the LayoutManager expects a context. MainActivity is a context, so we pass MainActivity to it. Normally you would just write 'this' but because we are now 'in the recyclerview' thanks to the with statement, 'this' would mean 'list'. Therefore -> `this@MainActivity` which is the same as `MainActivity.this` in java terms.

Answer (score 0):

That is the context similar to

```
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

`this@MainActivity` points the Current Class instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can get a reference to your `MainActivity`  by using

```
this@MainActivity
```